# Video views counter in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, video

I uploaded a video in SharePoint Online(Asset Library) and after full crawl of the video, I could see the video views count. But counter doesn't increment immediately after few more views and i can see the view counts change only after a day's time. 

I would like to know 

1)if it requires a full crawl even for view counts to increment?

2)is there a way to get the list of users who viewed the video?

Comment: just an option: try using Stream with the Stream webpart: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-stream-web-part-b97fa87c-1337-4271-a059-17f0d2b26e8b

Comment: thanks for the response. Looks like my subscription doesn't include Stream subscription. I did not find this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't require a full crawl for view counts to increment.

All view counts and statistics are only calculated once per day. As a result, there will be a 1-2 day delay on when views are tabulated.

We cannot get the users who viewed the video.

View statistics for a video in Office 365 Video for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-statistics-for-a-video-in-office-365-video-46819666-2b24-4220-882d-aeceaf10a745

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see the views count only on Classic SharePoint experience and not on modern view, any idea on if this is expected.